# Network Password Recovery

Tags: password-recovery, hashing

I am trying to recover a password for my network. It's set up like this: a network of computers, and a central server which authenticates login-passwords entered, and is also a network share. Username looks like administrator@abc. I tried to recover the password hashes from the individual CPUs, they gave this : FAFEA8FAF0D8D61FAAD3B435B51404EE. This decodes to GAGCAU and a null hash after. This password does not work for logging in to the network. Is there a way to recover the password for the network share from a non-admin network account?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just change the password using any number of tools?

Comment: What operating system(s) are you using? If you're using windows you will have a very hard time recovering passwords, resetting them would be your best bet.

Comment: XP, and how do you reset a password? I'm sorry, I inherited this network so I don't really know how it's set up.

Comment: 1. Networks don't have passwords. Network devices (computers) have passwords. 2. `a central server which authenticates login-passwords entered, and is also a network share` is probably a domain controller for Active Directory. 3. If you're going to work on this stuff start using the correct terminology. It's harder for us to help you if we have to "decode" what you're referring to.

Comment: I'm sorry. As I said, I inherited this network when the person managing it before left, so I'm not too familiar. We are looking for someone more knowledgeable, but haven't been able to find one yet. So, is it possible to extract hashes from the domain controllers?

Comment: @Sneaky Do you have physical access to the server? If you do, than you should run OPHCrack there, to get the admin password.
If you don't, than I'm afraid it's a lost cause.
The only possible solution left is brute-forcing, which is quite easy to execute, but that can take a really long time (somewhere between days and years).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to reset the password for a windows XP account, you can do so by using one of many free LiveCDs which will go through the process in a nice little interface.

Take a look at: [OphCrack](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ss/ophcracksbs.htm) which is an auto-password recover tool based on Rainbow Tables.

Also, try the [Offline PAssword and Registry Editor for NT (incl XP)](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/)

Hopefully one of these will get you up and running again.

Comment: That's the problem, I used OphCrack and got the Windows password. But all my stuff is stored on the network share, which I lost the password to.